# KQL cast numerics to dynamic

Tags: type-conversion, kql, azure-data-explorer

I need to cast some numeric data directly to `dynamic`. Consider [the following case](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAAy2O0QrDIAxF3/2KvFUhjPkq7EvGKHGGIlUZ1o627OOXuiUkkMPhkkBN2ifWCqRicBBLw34k8pwcLK3GMiF09qa0soPKlJS5d2QRhm1AsJfrXzrJ3olF9VAf4K1xCeBpgtu5xxc9Z93z8RdpxFrWnKnGgyHTzKN4WsaA3+WvL1AYf+SpAAAA):

```
datatable(
    id: int,
    label: string, 
    value: real
)[
    1, 'x', 1.0, 
    1, 'y', 1.1,
]
| extend bag = bag_pack(label, value)
| summarize make_bag(bag) by id
```

| id | bag_bag |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | {"x":1.0,"y":1.1} |

> *Please note: if you're accessing this from the ADX Web UI, the stored `dynamic` values are massaged for display. Add `| extend dynamic_to_json(bag_bag)` [to compare](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1RC0d.png)

I know `x` values will always be whole numbers and I want to cast to integer before packing the bag. The [`iff()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/ifffunction) function however requires that both expressions be of the same explicit type. Thus, the [following expression](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA0WPUQuDIBSF3/0Vl72kIGO9Bv2SMeKat3CpjbJRYz9+6qIUhfN5LueoMcStLHEGcRldgfFBZmFRka1gDpPxvYTM3mgXqmAitEzcMyolFGshobzedlMiWyalZA/2BVoDeQ0Ke6jT3bywHfgZss+ZrvvD4wHqGi7rRR40jLEezy3ESbPOSjAR8+bFOZzMh8DhQE1M5PEIUFv84dlHbx6daZswNs959MmTvOIHiEoB6xUBAAA=)...

```
| extend bag = bag_pack(
    label, 
    iff(
        label == "x",
        toint(value),
        value
    )
)
```

...fails with...

> Call to iff(): @then data type (int) must match the @else data type (real)

...and the [obvious workaround](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA22P0QqDIBSG732Kw25SkLFug55kDDmmhUttlI0ae/ipRd1M8cD5/v9wfhWGeKXVlEA8RlVgfOC5sSi1rWAKo/Edh8zeaGddwajREnbPqORQLAWH8nrbTYmsmZScPMgX9BK0VyCxgzpV8cKmp+eSfc607QYPAeoaLsuFHzQMavXoTEPDEIPSnIeJf4ZNygIjLKaYZudwNB8NDnstYg4aHwO5xn+fKfd5EQbxnAafPMnLfnQbhY8rAQAA)...

```
| extend bag = bag_pack(
    label, 
    iff(
        label == "x",
        todynamic(toint(value)),
        todynamic(value)
    )
)
```

...fails with...

> todynamic(): argument #1 expected to be a string expression

`todynamic()` is a deprecated alias for [`parse_json()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/parsejsonfunction) rather than part of the [`tostring()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/tostringfunction)/[`toint()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/tointfunction)/etc group of functions; and is not fit for this purpose. Is there another workaround I can use to directly cast my numerics to `dynamic`?

Answer (score 1):

> I know `x` values will always be whole numbers and I want to cast to integer before packing the bag.

I have reproduced in my environment and below are my expected results:

**`The KQL query which worked for me:`**

```
datatable(
    id: int,
    label1: string, 
    value: real
)[
    2, 'x', 2.0, 
    2, 'y', 2.1,
]
| extend bag = bag_pack(
    label1, 
    parse_json(
        iff(
            label1 == "x",
            todynamic(tostring(toint(value))),
            todynamic(tostring(value))
        )
    )
)
| summarize make_bag(bag) by id
```

**`Output:`**

[image]

[Fiddle.](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA4VQ2wqDMAx9F/yH4MtaKGPzUfBLxpCo2ehWq9Q6dOzjF2/ontbQNjk5SXtSomfLDYkwAF66TEBbr%20bIYE7mnEDrnbZ3BTP6QtNRAo7QhIG8zGCs4NAfFMTH08oboWGCztzvGgYfoN6TLSHHO6TjmTVYPMX%20sbW4QddS9mhru6Sn391uu2grgjSFqI/Ub87X5WCx0oXw9ayAHRYnJgFSyv/8hbnxFpcvOeppu6pCp98EFT4pY0WCt4R84El%20AbahdVdcAQAA)

Comment:  curious... This is the first this I tried but for some reason I was ending up with stringified values, e.g. `{"x":"2","y":"2.1"}` although I cannot seem to repro that behavior quickly at this time. Perhaps that's another question though.

Comment: I got the expected value as shown in output screen shot too

Answer (score 0):

Extending 2 columns...

- 1 packed as `real`
- 1 packed as `int`

...allows us to choose a common type for the `iff()` statement.

Execute in [[Web](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA22QwQqDMBBE7/mKxYsJLKVeBb+kFNnUVYLRFo1FSz++aywVoQmBZOZlMqSiINN61gpkuCoH1weMB0+WfQ5jGFzfIETtSX7iHAYmr8wlShlCOqcI2en8hVZliUqG6qrewHPgvtpMS025Xocibh90a3V8Cbdwgz9MmsAfLNzF0Bts9nTBBHZ1rff2UBSQzMkhEg811JowTl1Hg3sxdNRyKZ6WZcAu8iMfpHDLGyMBAAA=)]

```
datatable(
    id: int,
    label: string, 
    value: real
)[
    1, 'x', 1.0, 
    1, 'y', 1.1,
]
| extend 
    bag_real = bag_pack(label, value),
    bag_int  = bag_pack(label, toint(value))
| extend bag = iff(
    label == "x",
    bag_int,
    bag_real
)
| summarize make_bag(bag) by id
```

| id | bag_bag |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | { "x":1, "y":1.1 } |